# Unexpected variable

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

I'm currently translating a mysql project into sqlsrv for a client and I just ran into a problem. Php is complaining about $query_pass being unexpected when in reality it's being declared. It worked when I used mysql but I can't see how the problem could even be remotely related to that. Here's the code:

```
    <?php

session_start();
ob_start();

?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<form action="<?php $current_file ?>" method="post">
        E-post: <input type="text" name="username"/><br>
        Lösenord: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Logga in"/>
        </form><form action="http://localhost/update.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Skapa lösenord">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['pass']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password))
    {

        $query = "SELECT login_id, password FROM users WHERE email = '$username'";
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
        $query_pass = $row['password'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['login_id']

        if($row && ($query_pass == NULL))
        {
            $next = "http://localhost/update.php";
                header('Location: '.$next);


        }
        else
        {
            if((sqlsrv_num_rows($query_run) == 0) || $query_pass != $password)
            {
                echo 'Ingen matchning av lösenord och användare hittad.';
            }else{
                $next = "http://localhost/title_choice.php";
                header('Location: '.$next);
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "Användarnamn och lösenord behövs.";
    }

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query_pass' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 28

Comment: You forgot a `;` on `$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing semi colon

Comment: The error you are getting is a *parse error*, it means you have a syntax error.  It has *nothing* to do with it being declared or not.  It means that PHP doesn't understand why you put that syntax in that spot.

Comment: Thanks! I also found other errors thanks to that! Now I'm on the right track, didn't thought to look for that! This code also has numerous problems with the query, the first being that I don't run it at all.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `;` at the following line:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Why downvote? As off topic as the question is this is 100% correct

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, too..strange ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['login_id']
```

needs the ;

Comment: That's correct, this would be the next error ;) +1